# Network communication between containers of two podman instances

Tags: networking, podman, podman-compose

I have a Debian 12 server with `user1` and `user2`.
`user1` is running podman with `container11` and `container12`.
`user2` is running podman with `container21` and `container22`.

podman is in both cases rootless and `user1` and `user2` have no access to each other's files.
I do the separation because of security reasons.

I'm using `podman-compose`. Each user has it's own `docker-compose.yaml`

`container11` has a port exposed to `localhost` as you can see in the `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
```

I need a solution, that `container21` can reach this port.

How can I do that the most secure way?

I already tried to use `host.containers.internal` in `container21` but I realized, that this doesn’t work, because podman runs rootless.

Can I maybe add a permission to `container21` to reach port 3306 of localhost?

Comment: In the meantime I noticed that reaching the host's localhost by `host.containers.internal` works well on my PC with Fedora 38 (even without an extra permission flag), but not on my Debian 12 server. Is it because of a bug in the podman version of Debian (4.3)? Or is it something I can configure? (Like you have to configure that you can rootless expose to a port under 1000)